# create custom two level object using arrays - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I have to create a custom object using two arrays which contains objects with two to three properties. Now based on number of matched items I have create the object. Here I don't want to use too many variables. Without using intermediate variables I want to write the code

**code**

```
var fn = function() {
  var list1 = [{aId: 0, name: 'item1'},
             {aId: 1, name: 'item2'},
             {aId: 2, name: 'item3'}],
    list2 = [ { id: 0, label: 'one', actions: [ 0, 1, 2 ] },
              { id: 1, label: 'two', actions: [ 0, 2 ] } ],
    customObj ={};
    for(var i=0; i<list1.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<list2.length; j++){
             customObj[list2[j].id] = {};
             for(var k=0; k<list2[j].actions.length; k++){
                 if(list1[i].aId == list2[j].actions[k]){
                     customObj[list2[j].id][list1[i].name] = true

                 }
             }
        }
    }
   return customObj;
}
```

**Required Output:**

```
customObj = {
   0: {
      item1: true,
      item2: true,
      item3: true
   },
   1: {
     item1:true,
     item3:true
   }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Inside loops you overwrite the result object (`customObj = {..}`), whereas you have to **add object property** (`customObj[propname] = {..}`).

Comment: @hindmost when I tried that I got `false` insted of  `{}`

Comment: That was a pseudocode. Don't conceive it literally. `propname` has to be replaced with index (`0`, `1`, ...)

Comment: @hindmost yes I tried based on index only. I have updated my code now but the thing was it captured only last element not all.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a value to the entire object instead of just the one property. Inside your condition, you just need `customObj[list2[j].id][list1[i].name] = true`. Using brackets to access the properties (as opposed to dots, as in `customObj.0.item1`) here lets you [assign those properties to variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). So, your final code would look like:

```
var fn = function() {
  var list1 = [{aId: 0, name: 'item1'},
             {aId: 1, name: 'item2'},
             {aId: 2, name: 'item3'}],
    list2 = [ { id: 0, label: 'one', actions: [ 0, 1, 2 ] },
              { id: 1, label: 'two', actions: [ 0, 2 ] } ],
    customObj ={};
    for(var i=0; i<list1.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<list2.length; j++){
            for(var k=0; k<list2.actions.length; k++){
                if(list1[i].aId == list2[j].actions[k]){
                    customObj[list2[j].id][list1[i].name] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return customObj;
}
```

Comment: I tried this way already I got error 'Cannot set property 'item1' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It is working with this piece of code and in it loops also reduced.

```
var fn = function() {
   var list1 = [{aId: 0, name: 'item1'},
                {aId: 1, name: 'item2'},
                {aId: 2, name: 'item3'}],
       list2 = [{ id: 0, label: 'one', actions: [ 0, 1, 2 ] },
                { id: 1, label: 'two', actions: [ 0, 2 ] } ],
       customObj ={};
       for(var i=0; i<list2.length; i++) {
            customObj[list2[i].id] = {};
            for(var j=0; j<list1.length; j++) {
                 if(list2[i].actions.indexOf(list1[j].aId) > -1)    
                     customObj[list2[i].id][list1[j].name] = true
            }
        }
 return customObj;
}
```